# Exporting basemap in ArcMap, similiar to export dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, basemap, png

I am trying to export the basemap in ArcMap to use it with my mosaic dataset. I need these 2 to import and work with in **[Unity 3D](http://unity3d.com/)**.

When I am exporting my mosaic dataset consisting of DEM files, I can right click on the dataset and click export. There I have the option to "use renderer" and "square", together with choosing to use either entire mosaic or current view dataset.

However, from what I can notice, the only way to export the basemap is to click file - export.

What is the problem:

- I need the exported DEM to match with the basemap when I export them as .png.
- If the exported basemap is different (different size/pixels) the basemap which is used as a projection over the imported DEM will not match (for example the sea will be projected into the mountainous region of my DEM)

Could anyone help me match these 2?

I do use photoshop to edit my DEM/basemap for importing into Unity (16bit, grayscale for DEM, etc).

Maybe is it possible to photoshop the exported basemap to match with my DEM?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to Export Map to export a PNG file with a world file.

The trick is to be in Data View when you do this.

See [Problem: When exporting to BMP, JPEG, TIFF, PNG and GIF from ArcMap, 'Write World File' is grayed out](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008403).